# Boolean satisfiability - algorithm

Tags: algorithm, satisfiability

I have a boolean formula: **(x_{1} or x_{2}) and (x_{3} or x_{4}) and ..... and (x_{2r-1} or x_{2r})**, where **x_{i}** belongs to the set: **{p_{1}, p_{2}, ... p_{99} , ~p_{1}, ~p_{2}, ... ~p_{99} }** and I have to determine if for some values of **x_{i}** given formula can be true.

I know that it is in general computationally difficult. But is there any quite fast way I can do this particular problem? So far I've tried backtracking - that is in recursion I substitude every possible value (0 or 1 so not many) for every possible variable and every variable, which hasn't got value yet, is trivially true. Before I go deeper into recursion I chceck the formula (even when not every variable has got a value) and if it is false, I don't go deeper. But it is too slow. Any ideas? I would be very grateful for help.

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem, but perhaps [Math.StackExchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/) could help you more with the algorithm development. We'll help you implement it though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only have two variables per OR clause, then you have [2-SAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability), which has a linear-time solution.